# ruby gem on windows 10 not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install sass with ruby on my windows machine `gem install sass` but it is not working.
I get the following error:

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

After googling around I found this workaround:
https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

The thing is that I already have an **AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem** in my ssl_certs directory.

`gem --version` shows `2.4.5.1`
I am using windows 10 and downloaded the installer from ruby website: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

`ruby -v` shows `ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [i386-mingw32]`

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into your gemfile and change the source to http://rubygems.org (lose the https://).

Comment: What do you mean with gemfile? I have a file called "gemfile" in C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\power_assert-0.2.2... But it already is setup to http://...

Comment: Apologies, that is the fix for rails. In ruby you should be able to use the command: "gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/" in your console with the http:// in front of rubygems